# How to get the js output inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I want to get my output in the pop up modal

My question was to create an array with ticket numbers

UI should have a button to select the winner. upon clicking the button

one of the lottery numbers should be randomly shown as the winner in the following way

1. inside the console

1. Inside an modal popup box

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    <p id="test"></p>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Lottey Winner</h2>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#myModal" data-target="#test" id="btn1" onclick="myFunction()">
          Winner
        </button>


        <div class="modal" id="myModal">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" >
                <p id="test"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
 

    <script>
    const a=["12","34","45","67"];
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
    console.log( a[random]);

    function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = a[random];
    }
    

        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried calling it using a a simple button juz to know if i am getting the output and i got the output I would say i only been studying js for 1 or 2 weeks

Comment: Your issue is not very clear, could you describe the wanted flow and the expected result ?